# My script is sending non-stop

Tags: bash, shell

My shell script below is sending non-stop even if the parameters are not being met already:

```
MAX=85
EMAIL="my@email.com"
PART=sda1
USE=`df -h |grep $PART | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d'%' -f1`
if [ $USE -gt $MAX ]; then
  echo "Percent used: $USE of /" | mail -s "Server is running out of disk space" $EMAIL
fi
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this. Add `set -x` to your script.

Comment: Also the `grep | awk | cut` is an antipattern; http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This server is running in AWS.  I looked at the email's headers and saw a queer IP address.  I traced the IP in AWS and found a replica of the original server I thought was sending out the mails.  It was cloned by a now-defunct vendor.  So, I just terminated that server and problem solved!  :D

This is a very good community!  The people are very gifted technically and are so whilling to share.  Keep it up, guys!  I appreciate all those who tried to help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working on my system. Perhaps check to make sure that the output of `dh` is always adding up to an amount greater than 85. You may have more success not using the -h argument to dh and instead retrieving the actual number in bytes and operating on that instead.

```
#!/bin/sh 

# Change this number accordingly as usual
MAX=100000000
EMAIL="my@email.com"
PART=sda1
USE=$( df | grep $PART | awk '{ print $3 }' )

if [ "$USE" -gt "$MAX" ]
then echo "Successful"
     #echo "Percent used: $USE of /" | mail -s "Server is running out of disk space" $EMAIL
fi
```

Or for the percentage perhaps try POSIX shell string cutting:

```
#!/bin/sh 

MAX=85
EMAIL="my@email.com"
PART=sda1
USE=$( df | grep $PART | awk '{ print $5 }' )

if [ "${USE%%%}" -gt "$MAX" ]
then echo "Successful"
     #echo "Percent used: $USE of /" | mail -s "Server is running out of disk space" $EMAIL
fi
```